# Is there any logic to adding a threshold to see if two variables are related?

Tags: data-mining, predictive-modeling, correlation

I have two variables $X$ and $Y$ given as tuples of $(x, y)$, and I want to see if there is a relationship between the two variables. I can do so by finding the correlation coefficient.

However, I found that by selecting an arbitrary subset of the data (e.g. $(x, y) | x > k$ ), I can get a higher correlation coefficient and a stronger result. Is doing so mathematically sound? I have no a priori reason to believe that certain data points are "more important" than others, to put it simply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not sound.  You're doing data dredging.

Try this thought experiment.  Suppose you generate random points (no actual relationship).  Then you compute the correlation coefficient of all the points; the correlation coefficient of all points where $x>k$; and the correlation coefficient of all points where $x<k$.  Realistically, one of the two latter values will be larger than the correlation coefficient of all the points. So you'll always be in a position where if you pick a threshold you can increase the correlation coefficient.  This is true even if the points are randomly generated.

Thus, your procedure introduces bias.

This is similar to the problem of p-hacking.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have a sample size effect on your correlation coefficient. You may find the following references useful:

- [At what sample size do correlations stabilize?](https://www.r-bloggers.com/at-what-sample-size-do-correlations-stabilize/)
- [The effects of sample size and variability on the correlation coefficient.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8776228)
- And also this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/280499/comparison-of-pearsons-r-from-samples-of-different-size) in stats.stackexchange demonstrating the effect of subsampling on correlation coefficient.